# Android Studio dark and light app themes

Tags: java, android-studio

I've build an app with two themes (dark and light). When i choose one of them it works but when i exit from the app and open again then its on the default one. How can I solve this?

Comment: save last state into sharedPreference

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreference` to store your user's preferred theme, and based on what was saved, load the respective theme.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using `SharePreferences`:

When you change the theme, simply save a value in the preference like for example : `type == dark`.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("theme", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("theme_key", "dark");
editor.apply();
```

When you get back to the app, read the stored them value in your preferences and set it accordingly!!

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("theme", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String theme = sp.getString("theme_key", "default");
```

Now, just check:

```
if(theme.equals("dark"){ //set here }
```

I hope this helps!